# What are the differences between the 4-DVD and 6-DVD box sets of Lost in Space (2018)?

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-2018

Has anyone bought the DVD box set for seasons 1–3 of the Netflix *Lost in Space* series?

There is a 4-DVD set and a 6-DVD set. I'm trying to find out the differences between them—and trying to see which one to buy, if any.

I can provide more details, if needed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  So, basically you want to know what the difference between the two releases is?  I'm not sure we can answer which is "better," but we might be able to tell you how they differ.

Comment: Hi. Yes. How they differ. If they both have the main series, but one includes extras like behind the scenes stuff, then the one that includes the extras would be better, in my opinion. Thanks.

Comment: The difference is ... 2 DVDs

Comment: @JK. - Damn. You stole my joke

Comment: I can't find either, to be honest. Can you provide a link to these boxsets?

Comment: Found 4 disc Blu-ray's only on eBay. Which seems odd... https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/155700666146?chn=ps&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&amdata=enc%3A1V6MdfaHnQ-KGglHYi-52sg49&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=710-134428-41853-0&mkcid=2&mkscid=101&itemid=155700666146&targetid=1647205088520&device=m&mktype=pla&googleloc=9044938&poi=&campaignid=17206177401&mkgroupid=136851690655&rlsatarget=pla-1647205088520&abcId=9300866&merchantid=764171847&gclid=Cj0KCQjw0vWnBhC6ARIsAJpJM6ff681OOPMNmSHcPrwjr6QJbN1irUn7S_9BrZy-YpDqXtuacLJ5XLYaApNTEALw_wcB

Comment: Here is a link to the 6 disc set: https://www.ebay.com/itm/155670961949?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=qtsftscnqae&sssrc=2349624&ssuid=fyajSvS2RfS&var=&widget_ver=artemis&media=EMAIL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the two links to eBay items accurately reflect the source of the original question.

[4 Disc](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/155700666146?chn=ps&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&amdata=enc%3A1V6MdfaHnQ-KGglHYi-52sg49&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=710-134428-41853-0&mkcid=2&mkscid=101&itemid=155700666146&targetid=1647205088520&device=m&mktype=pla&googleloc=9044938&poi=&campaignid=17206177401&mkgroupid=136851690655&rlsatarget=pla-1647205088520&abcId=9300866&merchantid=764171847&gclid=Cj0KCQjw0vWnBhC6ARIsAJpJM6ff681OOPMNmSHcPrwjr6QJbN1irUn7S_9BrZy-YpDqXtuacLJ5XLYaApNTEALw_wcB)
[6 Disc](https://www.ebay.com/itm/155670961949?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=qtsftscnqae&sssrc=2349624&ssuid=fyajSvS2RfS&var=&widget_ver=artemis&media=EMAIL)

Then the difference would appear to be a dedicated 3 seasons set Vs a collection of the individual seasons releases.

Each season released a two disc set giving a total of 6 discs.

The whole 1-3 release appears to be just a 4 disc collection. Content wise I can't tell if anything has changed because both products are eBay items and the details sections are... sketchy.

The four disc item in particular has references to Moon Knight and Star Trek : Picard in the description.

Given both items show up on eBay and not on any primary retailer sites that I can find, I personally wouldn't trust either of these products to deliver what they say on the listings.

Comment: They both look like illegal sets.

Comment: Thanks. I figured as much. Just wanted to see if anyone here had been daring enough to buy either one. Doesn't sound like it, and it won't be me!